# Android - Eclipse is slow to build/run using project on SDK 2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I've been working on my Android app for a while, initially targeting version 2.1 (API level 7).  I've now changed the `min/target SDK to 2.2 (API level 8)` in order to support Google `Cloud Messaging`.

Since this change I've noticed the time to build and run the project in Eclipse has greatly increased.

I don't use the emulator (too slow anyway) and run direct to my phone, and it takes upto 20 seconds to build/run when I just make a minor change in one .java file.  It was much quicker when targeting 2.1.

Is there anything I can tweak in Eclipse to improve things?

I'm using `Eclipse Juno 4.2.0`.  My PC is Windows 7, Intel Core2 Duo CPU @1.4Ghz, 5GB RAM.

Comment: Sometimes I clean project(Project->Clean...) and it helps. But generally it's not very fast.
Other options are run it from command line or use intellij IDEA which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that eclipse.ini doesn't contains a similar line:

```
CompileThreshold=5
```

If it does, just remove any CompileThreshold specifications from your config.